# Change from read.csv to read_csv to load file, then graph is not shown

Tags: r

I first used read.csv to load file, and graph a histogram. Then I changed to read_csv. My histogram is not working now. The error says:

"Unknown or uninitialised column: 'First.Income'. "

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf<- read_csv("households.csv")

hist(mydf$First.Income,main="Histogram of First Income")
```

Answer (score 5):

`read_csv` stores headers a bit differently than `read.csv` does. Whereas the latter turns spaces into periods, the former reads them with the spaces. So your column names are different when you load your data with `read_csv`.

We don't have your data to evaluate for sure, but I assume that the following will work for you instead:

```
mydf<- read_csv("households.csv")

hist(mydf$`First Income`,main="Histogram of First Income")
```

Comment: @Lin If this answer is helpful, please accept this answer.